# When an sqlite3 query returns ? for some character, what does this mean about the underlying data? How do I view that data in its unicode form?

Tags: android, sql, unicode, sqlite

I'm receiving: ������ back from sqlite3 queries, and I'm trying to determine what that means about the underlying data.  These characters are supposed to be Cyrillic alphabet characters.  These queries are on my desktop.

I am attempting to render them on an Android application, however the values returned from the related queries in the Android application (when viewed in the debugger at-least) are:

\u0003Ȓ\u0001-500-300

In the text view I show them in I see a number of empty squares.

I believe there must be some kind of encoding issue somewhere, but I'm sure how to check and see what actual values are stored in the db, vs what I'm getting back etc...

Comment: you need to maintain the same charset through the ENTIRE pipeline. client, server, connections to the db, db tables, etc... if you have a different charset at any stage, you'll get corruption like this.

Comment: So it's corruption then?  Your comment makes a lot of sense.  The db is generated from a db dump from an external source, and I suspect that in the generation of my db there is a conversion to utf-8 that I didn't handle.

Comment: yes. if you insert utf8 text into an (say) iso8859 table, then any multi-byte UTF chars get mangled into single-byte iso8859 chars, which generally manifests itself as `Ã`-type accented chars showing up

Comment: Thanks a lot.  They were 7bit ascii encoded files into a utf-8 db.